# S4 object in R cannot be passed to Fortran

Tags: r, r-s4

I use the `bdiag` function in the `Matrix` package in R to generate diagonal matrix, and then I pass the resultant matrix (called `mat`) into a self-written function but R fails to execute due to the following error:

`Error: invalid mode (S4) to pass to Fortran (arg 1)`

I checked `isS4(mat)` and it's `TRUE`. Thus, I guess there is a way to convert the S4 object somehow in order to be passed to the function. Any advice will be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE: I use the following codes for constructing the block diagonal matrix:

```
grp.ids <- as.factor(c(rep(1,8), rep(2,4), rep(3,2)))
x <- model.matrix(~grp.ids)
X <- do.call(bdiag, replicate(238, x, simplify=FALSE))
```

Is there any other way to get a S3 matrix without using the `bdiag` function? Thanks!

Comment: Please see [this][1] for a solution.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13062164/repeat-a-matrix-many-times-and-get-a-vector-of-matrix-names

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only the `.Call()` interface can pass full R objects down to C or C++ code, see Section 5 of the Writing R Extensions manual.  With `.Fortran()` and `.C()` you are limited to basic vectors of `int`, `double`, ... and their corresponding Fortran types.

Comment: thank you for the comment! So, if I wanna use my function, how can I construct a S3 block diagonal matrix? I've updated my post above. Thanks again :)