# repeat a matrix many times and get a vector of matrix names

Tags: r

I have a basic matrix `mat` and I hope to get an R object `x = (mat, mat, ...)` where `mat` is repeated for 100 times. If this is possible, then I can pass `x` to a function which takes a vector of matrix names. I tried `rep(mat, 100)` but it seems that the matrix class is no longer maintained. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Update: Basically I plan to use

```
grp.ids <- as.factor(c(rep(1,8), rep(2,4), rep(3,2)))
x <- model.matrix(~grp.ids)
do.call(blockMatrixDiagonal,
             replicate(100, x, simplify=FALSE))
```

where the `blockMatrixDiagonal` function can be found [here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/block-diagonal-matrices-in-r/). Then R gives an error: number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length. What I really hope to get via these coding is a block diagonal matrix. Thanks :)

Comment: What do you mean by `(mat, mat, ..)`? Do you mean you want to get a `rows` x `100*cols` matrix back out? a `100*rows` x `cols` matrix back out? a list where `x[[1]] == mat`? Can you give a simple example (say a 2x3 matrix) and what the "function which takes a vector of matrix names" is? (Note, a vector of matrix names is not the same as a vector of matrices! (I don't even know what you mean by "vector of matrix *names*" - you mean the character string 'mat'?))

Comment: @mathematical.coffee: thanks for the comments! Actually the function I plan to use requires a list of matrices as its argument, which it will make a big block diagonal matrix based on these passed matrices. What I hope to pass to the function is a repetition of matrix names `mat`, for 100 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input matrix is not appropriate for building a *block diagonal matrix* since it's not a square matrix (i.e., the number of rows equals the number of columns).

Let me cite two resources on block diagonal matrices.

1) [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_diagonal_matrices):

> A block diagonal matrix is a block matrix which is a square matrix, and having main diagonal blocks square matrices

2) The description of the function [`blockMatrixDiagonal`](http://www.r-bloggers.com/block-diagonal-matrices-in-r/):

> builds a block matrix whose diagonals are the square matrices provided.

---

You can combine your non-square matrices with the function `adiag` from the package `magic`. With your matrix `x`:

```
library(magic)
do.call(adiag, replicate(100, x, simplify = FALSE))
```

Comment: thank you for the comments! Yes, I realize that the `blockMatrixDiagonal` function takes square matrices only. However, maybe the term "block diag. matrix" is not very appropriate, but it is possible to make non-square matrices as "blocks" and then make a matrix similar to block diagonal, with all other elements == 0. I used the `bdiag` function in `Matrix` but it returns a S4 object impossible to be passed to my function...

Answer (score 2):

For a base R solution, check out `kronecker`

```
?kronecker
# For your block diagonal matrix:
kronecker(diag(1, 100), x)
# or with `%x%` alias
diag(1, 100) %x% x

# example 1
m <- matrix(1:6, nrow = 3)
kronecker(diag(1, 2), m)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    4    0    0
# [2,]    2    5    0    0
# [3,]    3    6    0    0
# [4,]    0    0    1    4
# [5,]    0    0    2    5
# [6,]    0    0    3    6

# example 2
matrix(1, nrow = 2, ncol = 3) %x% m
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
# [1,]    1    4    1    4    1    4
# [2,]    2    5    2    5    2    5
# [3,]    3    6    3    6    3    6
# [4,]    1    4    1    4    1    4
# [5,]    2    5    2    5    2    5
# [6,]    3    6    3    6    3    6
```